# Parse multipart file with Node/Express and upload to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express

I am receiving a multipart file via a REST service call to a vendors API. This file includes XML data and blob data for two images. I need to be able to split and store these as individual files using Node/Express. I have seen a lot posts/resources on multipart form data, but my needs are parsing this using JavaScript into individual files that can then be uploaded into Azure Blob Storage. I suspect Node/Express or a Node module such as request (https://github.com/request/request) would be the right way to go, but haven't found anything concrete. Here is an example of the multipart file. Note that there is not filename for the multipart file:

```
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461"

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=Texture_1.png
Content-ID: response-1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Texture_1.png

‰PNG
"blob data here"

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=manifest.xml
Content-ID: response-2
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dae_root>blank_3D.dae</dae_root>

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=texture_3D.dae
Content-ID: response-3
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=texture_3D.dae

<xml data here... lots of xml data>

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=Texture_0.png
Content-ID: response-4
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Texture_0.png

‰PNG
"blob image data"
```

Comment: Are you available to supply a complete xml file content for a easy testing?

Comment: Of course @GaryLiu-MSFT, try this link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46697217/MultipartTest

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it looks like this is a purely node.js issue instead of an Azure related one - feel free to correct me if I have any misunderstood. In this case, I recommend us to leverage below two modules to solve the issue:

https://github.com/isaacs/multipart-js/

https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Sample multipart-js parser below for your quick reference:

```
var multipart = require("multipart");

// parsing
var parser = multipart.parser();

// in all event handlers, "this" is the parser, and "this.part" is the
// part that's currently being dealt with.
parser.onpartbegin = function (part) { doSomething(part) };
parser.ondata = function (chunk) { doSomethingElse(chunk) };
parser.onend = function () { closeItUp() };

// now start feeding the message through it.
// you can do this all in one go, if you like, or one byte at a time,
// or anything in between.
parser.boundary = "foo";
var chunk;
while ( chunk = upstreamThing.getNextChunk() ) {
  parser.write(chunk);
}
parser.close();
```

Comment: This is helpful. In my case, I need to upload the parts to Azure Blob Storage once parsed.

Comment: Multipart does not look likes it working/ready for prime time. I haven't seen any examples with formidable. Do you have one with formidable?